# Is there a apply-function-to-region-lines in emacs?

Tags: function, emacs, macros, elisp

A lot of my work involves searching and deleting unnecessary lines of code. So I create a macro, and then select all lines `(C-x h)` and then run the command `(apply-macro-to-region-lines)`. I managed to save that command and placed it in my `.emacs` file; I called it `cut_it_now`. But now my function is not a macro anymore, so I can't use the `(apply-macro-to-region-lines)` function anymore. 
Do you know if there is `(apply-function-to-region-lines)` implemented somewhere?

Many thanks,

D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Lindydancer's answer, and I'd also add that there might be an easier way to accomplish your goal. e.g. the built-in function `delete-matching-lines`. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Note that you can still use `apply-macro-to-region-lines` with a macro generated from code, *provided* the macro is defined as a vector or string. With a custom `apply-named-macro-to-region-lines`[2], you can select the macro to use interactively.

Emacs has two ways of generating code from a keyboard macro, depending upon the method used to name it.

If you use `kmacro-name-last-macro` (bound to <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-k</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>), then Emacs generates a *function* from the macro, which is not directly useful for this particular purpose [1].

If you use `name-last-kbd-macro` to name your macro, it will be generated as a vector or string.

In either case, you then use `insert-kbd-macro` to obtain the code.

In fact the vector/string format is the default, so you could bypass the naming step and immediately ask for the code (typing <kbd>RET</kbd> at the name prompt to indicate the most recently-defined macro), and then manually edit the default name of the inserted code.

[1]: The vector form does appear to simply be embedded in the function definition, so you should be able to extract that from the code to manually re-define a macro function in vector format.

[2]: When I originally wrote this reply, I'd forgotten that this was a custom function. Sorry about that.

```
(defun apply-named-macro-to-region-lines (top bottom)
  "Apply named keyboard macro to all lines in the region."
  (interactive "r")
  (let ((macro (intern
                (completing-read "kbd macro (name): "
                                 obarray
                                 (lambda (elt)
                                   (and (fboundp elt)
                                        (or (stringp (symbol-function elt))
                                            (vectorp (symbol-function elt))
                                            (get elt 'kmacro))))
                                 t))))
    (apply-macro-to-region-lines top bottom macro)))
```

Answer (score 5):

The following function should do what you want:

```
(defun apply-function-to-region-lines (fn)
  (interactive "aFunction to apply to lines in region: ")
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (region-end))
    (let ((end-marker (copy-marker (point-marker)))
          next-line-marker)
      (goto-char (region-beginning))
      (if (not (bolp))
          (forward-line 1))
      (setq next-line-marker (point-marker))
      (while (< next-line-marker end-marker)
        (let ((start nil)
              (end nil))
          (goto-char next-line-marker)
          (save-excursion
            (setq start (point))
            (forward-line 1)
            (set-marker next-line-marker (point))
            (setq end (point)))
          (save-excursion
            (let ((mark-active nil))
              (narrow-to-region start end)
              (funcall fn)
              (widen)))))
      (set-marker end-marker nil)
      (set-marker next-line-marker nil))))
```

So, if you have the following function that you want to apply against lines in a buffer:

```
(defun test()
  (insert "> "))
```

And, if your buffer contains the following contents:

```
Line 1: blah, blah
Line 2: blah, blah
Line 3: blah, blah
Line 4: blah, blah
```

If you select a region enclosing just lines 2 & 3, enter "M-x apply-function-to-region-lines", and enter "test" as the function name when prompted, you will get the following result in your buffer:

```
Line 1: blah, blah
> Line 2: blah, blah
> Line 3: blah, blah
Line 4: blah, blah
```

Comment: Why do you narrow every single line?

Answer (score 4):

A simple solution is to define a macro that calls your function then use the good ol' `apply-macro-to-region-lines`.

Apart from that, I think that you could write a loop in a few lines of elisp that does exactly what you ask for. If you would like to be fancy, you can even prompt the user for the name of the function. I think this is a good exercise for elisp, I can help you with some pointers if you feel like you would like to try it yourself.

Answer (score -1):

You could always copy the source to `apply-macro-to-region-lines` and tweak it to call a passed in function, and thus make your own version.