# Replace region with result of calling a function on region

Tags: emacs, elisp

How would I write an interactive function that takes a function and replaces the currently selected region with the result of calling that function on the region.

I see this answer: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/6539916/625365

But that's calling the function once per line, not giving it the region as an argument, and it seems like a lot of code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could do some trickery around `filter-buffer-substring`, but that seems like an obscure function, at least to me. On the other hand, doing so in Emacs Lisp directly doesn't seem complicate:

```
(defun apply-function-to-region (fn)   
  (interactive "XFunction to apply to region: ")   
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((beg (region-beginning))
           (end (region-end))
           (resulting-text 
            (funcall 
             fn 
             (buffer-substring-no-properties beg end))))
      (kill-region beg end)
      (insert resulting-text))))
```

Then you can use a function that accepts and produces text (say `capitalize`), and capitalize the region. The function will ask for a function to apply. Finally, the deleted text is saved in the kill ring.

Comment: saving the killed text to the kill ring is a particularly nice touch. Thanks!

Comment: Suggest use (interactive "XFunction to apply to region: ") instead, so can write lambdas on fly. Like that: M-x apply-function-to-region RET (lambda(arg) (apply 'string (reverse (string-to-list arg)))) RET

Comment: You're right. I'll change the line. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5):

```
(defun apply-to-region (func)
  (unless (use-region-p)
    (error "need an active region"))
  (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
  (insert (funcall func)))

(defun foo ()
  ""
  "foobar")

(defun my/test ()
  (interactive)
  (apply-to-region 'foo))
```

To test it, select some text and run <kbd>M-x</kbd>`my/test`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

Comment: This calls the function, but I want to give `func` the current region as a string, and replace the region with the result.  `(funcall func (buffer-substring (mark) (point)))` works, but I have to comment out `delete-region` otherwise nothing gets passed in.

Comment: Something like this seems to work: `(let ((res (funcall func (buffer-substring (mark) (point)))))
    (delete-region (region-beginning) (region-end))
    (insert res))` - update your answer so I can accept it?